# duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementContentProvider.class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

This error started appearing after I updated firebase SDK on my project. If i try to build the project normally its working fine. but whenever trying to build a signed APK its giving the following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForProductionRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementContentProvider.class

here are my project dependencies. not sure where the duplication is occurring.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(name: 'google-maps-sdk-m4b', ext: 'aar')
    compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.7'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.3.5@aar'
    compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.0' 
} 

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This kind of error that you encountered is because of other jar dependency that have the same class. Also make sure that you have not added the support jar for both as gradle and jar dependency. I could not try it but, make sure you follow the steps here in adding the [Mobile SDK for work](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/mobile/previous-mobile-sdk-android#add_the_sdk_to_your_project). Another way is to try to build the dependencies individually to know in what part of it caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured solution to the problem. Adding `exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'` solved the issue:

```groovy
compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.+@aar') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by changing

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

In project level gradle file